# assumption of well-ordering principle

Tags: abstract-algebra, well-orders

An abstract algebra book says "the basic assumption here is 'well-ordering principle' : any nonempty set of nonnegative integers has a smallest member." and then using it, the book proves mathematical induction. Can we assume well-ordering principle because it is a theorem?

Comment: You haven't identified the book and you haven't said what its "well-ordering principle" states. If it states that every set can be well-ordered, then this is equivalent to the axiom of choice (AC). However, the principle of proof by mathematical induction over the natural numbers does not require AC. Please give some more details about what your book actually says.

Comment: If you're working with the positive integers, user, you can take well-ordering as an axiom and prove induction, or you can take induction as an axiom and prove well-ordering.

Comment: But see the very interesting paper, Öhman, L., Are Induction and Well-Ordering Equivalent?. Math Intelligencer 41, 33–40 (2019). https://doi.org/10.1007/s00283-019-09898-4 available at https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00283-019-09898-4 where it is noted that if you take the Peano postulates and replace induction with well-ordering then you can't prove induction, as the ordinal $\omega+\omega$ is a model for the modified Peano postulates but $\omega$ has no predecessor so induction doesn't work.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you very much for the reference! I thought abstract algebra is based on set theory and everything in abstract algebra has to be derivable from set theory. A lot of things are mixed in my head so I am confused.

Comment: There's more than one way to define the natural numbers. You can define them as sets in, say, Zermelo-Frankel set theory; you can define them as an ordered integral domain with induction or (equivalently, in this case) well-ordering; you can define them by the Peano axioms. Everything (in algebra) *can* be derived from set theory, but that doesn't imply that set theory is the only, or even the best, way to define any particular algebraic concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the well-ordering property of the integers follows from the construction of $\Bbb N$ (or $\omega$) in standard set theory (minimal inductive set, e.g.) It's a theorem of ZF.

Comment: Indeed, galactically less than ZF is needed.